# Duplicate File error in Adobe Air Native Extension for Android with Packaged Dependency

Tags: android, air, adobe

I've been working on an Ubertesters ANE for Android/iOS, starting with Android, and I've managed to get it to package the Ubertesters sdk as a depedency however when I build my game I get this as a result.

aapt tool failed:C:\Users****\AppData\Local\Temp\4cefa32a-ef1e-4f66-ba1c-06c2b 6a3289c\res\values\colors.xml: error: Duplicate file. C:\Users****\AppData\Local\Temp\3c65dec5-4ebe-4b94-b90c-c3164cdefb12 \captive_runtime_res\values\colors.xml: Original is here.

Suggestions/Thoughts?

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean "as a dependency" ? It seems that the JAR packaged with the ANE contains an Android resource file which name is conflicting with one of AIR internal files. BTW adding the AIR version would help too